# C# How to find who changed the SelectedIndex of a control

Tags: c#, combobox, event-handling

I have a *ComboBox*, and I need to now which function from the code raised the *SelectedIndexChanged* event, or if the index was changed by user action on form. 
In other words, I need to pass to the *SelectedIndexChanged* event some text:

"User action" - if the user changed the index by mouse manipulation

or

"FunctionName" - the function that do the index modification (for example somewhere inside function is present *SelectedIndex=1*)

Comment: You cannot add extra arguments to an event.  Simply use a *bool* field in your class.  Set it to true in code that messes with the combobox.  If you see it set to *false* in your SelectedIndexChanged event handler then you know it was the user that changed it.  Do note that this is a code smell, it should not matter how the selection got changed.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a very elegant solution but a simple one. Also you need to test it. Also I am assuming you are talking about winforms.

You can use the `Tag` property of combobox. You can set the property in the function as your "FunctionName" and then call the selectedindex from that function. Of course you will get the object of combobox in the `sender` parameter of `SelectedIndexChanged` handler.

If the user has changed it then the `Tag` property will be `null`. Also you would need to reset the property to `null` in your `SelectedIndexChanged` handler so that it is ready to listen to change events going forward.

Hope this helps.